# Install nodejs dependencies for subprojects in heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, deployment, build, buildpack

I have the nodejs project with the following structure

- topLevelProject

  - subproject1 (with package.json and its dependencies)
  - subproject2 (with package.json and its dependencies)

I deploy it to heroku using their nodejs buildpack.
But the problem is it downloads and installs only the dependencies from topLevelProject's package.json. So I have to add all dependencies as runtime dependencies in top level package.json.

How can I instruct heroku or heroku nodejs buildpack to install dependencies from subprojects' package.json in their respective node_modules?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution:

in topLevelProject I add the following script:

```
"scripts": {
  "heroku-postbuild": "npm --prefix subproject1 run installDep && npm --prefix subproject2 run installDep",
  "start": ...
},
```

In subprojects I add the following:

```
"scripts": {
  "installDep": "npm install"
},
```

To install also devDependencies in Heroku project settings I set config var

> NODE_ENV

to

> demo